# Wait for Firebase response while saving data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving form data to firebase and I want to wait for success before showing alert. How can I achieve this? I am using below code:

```
var submitInquiry = function () {
  // Get input values from each of the form elements
  var name = $("#student-name").val();
  var contact = $("#student-contact").val();
  var email = $("#student-email").val();
  var board = $("#student-board").val();
  var subject = $("#student-subject").val();
  var standard = $("#student-class").val();
  var message = $("#student-message").val();

  // Push a new inquiry to the database using those values
  var inquiryInstance =  inquiry.push();
  inquiryInstance.push({
    "name": name,
    "contact": contact,
    "email": email,
    "board": board,
    "subject": subject,
    "standard": standard,
    "message": message,
  }); 

  alert("Thank You! Your request has been received and our team will connect with you shortly.");
};
```

Comment: Do you get any response from firebase on whether the data was saved successfully?

Comment: How to get response from firebase in code. I can check on console for saved value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're calling `push()` twice, which really doesn't make sense.  So I'll assume that you only meant to call it once.

[According to the API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) push() returns a "ThennableReference", which is really just to say that it returns a promise that resolves after the operation is complete.  Use this promise to execute some other callback function to do what you want after the write is done:

```
inquiry.push({ ... }).then(() => {
    alert(...)
})
```

Comment: It is working fine now but the problem is from doesn't refresh after showing alert. When I used 'location.reload(); method after showing alert', it is not showing alert, only refresh the form.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue.  Please ask a whole new question on Stack Overflow to explain what the new issue is.

Comment: Thanks. Let me draft another one for this